# Use 301 redirect in htaccess on a server with multiple domain names to affect only 1 domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have a server with 3 directories on it in the root and in the root with the 3 directories is a `.htaccess` file. Each directory points to a separate domain name.

- `directoryA` = `xamplea.com`
- `directoryB` = `xampleb.com`
- `directoryC` = `xamplec.com`

I want to have 301 redirect code in the `.htaccess` file in the root so all files in `xamplea.com` redirect to `https://xamplea.com` with:

- `xampleb.com` remaining unaffected.

and

- `xamplec.com` remaining unaffected.

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond xamplea.com ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://xamplea.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

but the above also redirects `xampleb.com` and `xamplec.com` to `https://xamplea.com` when I only want `xamplea.com` to be redirected to `https://xamplea.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[OR]` in `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` since you want both conditions to be true in order to redirect. Also, your second condition is not valid, you probably want to check the domain name.

This would give you:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xamplea\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) xamplea.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: "The third line doesn't work either." - Actually, the third line was OK. It's different to your line, but the result is the same.

Comment: the code proposed by Olivier causes an internal server error when accessing xampleb.com or xamplec.com. i don't know why there is a $ after the com in the second condition?

Comment: @P.Pei Check your error log for details of the internal server error. "when accessing xampleb.com" - do you mean when accessing a the domain `xampleb.com` (as in `http://xampleb.com/<something>`) or just the subdirectory `xampleb.com` (on some other domain)?

Comment: "when accessing xampleb.com" meant when i typed http:/xampleb.com into a browser to see whether i was redirected to https:/xamplea.com, which is what i did not want or stayed on http:/xampleb.com which is what i want.

Comment: The answer was to modify Olivier's code to:
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xamplea\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) xamplea.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: @DocRoot Interesting, I think it's the first time I see variables used in the redirection like that.

Comment: @P.Pei The ($) dollar sign at the end is to signify the end of the string in a regular expression. Meaning that the condition wouldn't be true if you had another domain like xamplea.company for example, but in your case I guess you can remove it.

Comment: @P.Pei "The answer was to modify Olivier's code to" - You'll also need a `RewriteBase /` directive for that to work - otherwise the redirect will likely break. (But do you really want to expose the `xamplea.com` subdirectory with an external redirect - shouldn't that be an _internal rewrite_?) However, this now does the _opposite_ to what you stated in the question, "all files in `xamplea.com` redirect to `https://xamplea.com`", as you are now _redirecting all requests to `https://xamplea.com` to the `xamplea.com` subdirectory_ - but maybe that was the intention to begin with?

Comment: i wanted for example http:/xamplea.com/file1.php to redirect to https:/xamplea.com/file1.php, http:/xamplea.com/file2.htm redirect to https:/xamplea.com/file1.htm etc.